# Uncaught type error - cannot read property 'length' of undefined in JQuery Autocomplete

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am trying to implement JQueryUI's Multiple value autocomplete however I am getting this error at line 464 of the main JQuery file (Jquery-2.1.0.js).

I am not sure of whether it is anything to do with my implementation which is below, or with the way I am referencing the Jquery and Jquery UI in my layout file. Please let me know:

**File reference in Layout**

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET MVC Application</title>
    <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />

    <link href="~/Content/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/Content/menuStyles.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>  
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.4.min.js"></script>

    <script src="~/Scripts/menu_jquery.js"></script>  
    <link href="~/Content/demos.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
</head>

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

**Bundle Config**

```
 public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryui").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

        // Use the development version of Modernizr to develop with and learn from. Then, when you're
        // ready for production, use the build tool at http://modernizr.com to pick only the tests you need.
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include("~/Content/demos.css"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/themes/base/css").Include(
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.core.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.resizable.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.selectable.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.accordion.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.autocomplete.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.button.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.dialog.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.slider.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.tabs.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.datepicker.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.progressbar.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.theme.css"));
    }
```

**And this is how I am implementing the Autocomplete plugin:**

I put all of this in a Partial View.

```
    <div class="ui-widget" style="text-align:left">
        <input id="city"/>
    </div> 

<style>
    .ui-autocomplete-loading {
        background: white url('Images/ui-anim_basic_16x16.gif') right center no-repeat;
    }
    #city { width: 25em; }
    </style>
<script>
    $(function () {

        debugger;
        $('#city').autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "Home/GetWhatever",
                    data: "{ 'pre':'" + request.term + "'}",
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    success: function (data) {
                        response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                            return {
                                SubCategoryName: item.SubCategoryName,
                                SubCategoryID: item.SubCategoryID,
                                json: item
                            }
                        }))
                    },
                    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        alert(textStatus);
                    }
                });
            },
            focus: function (event, ui) {
                $('#city').val(ui.item.SubCategoryName);
                return false;
            },
            select: function (event, ui) {
                $('#city').val(ui.item.SubCategoryID);
                return false;
            },
        }).data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
            return $("<li>")
            .append("<a>Company:" + item.SubCategoryName + "<br>Industry: " + item.SubCategoryID + "</a>")
            .appendTo(ul);
        };
    });
```

Please let me know if anything is wrong with the above.

Many thanks in advance.

**Update**

I have got this to work with a bit of tweaking of my referencing as below:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET MVC Application</title>
    <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />

    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>  

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")

    <link href="~/Content/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/Content/menuStyles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="~/Scripts/menu_jquery.js"></script>  
    <link href="~/Content/demos.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
</head>
<body> 


    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

I have also changed this:

response($.map(data.d, function (item) {

to this:

response($.map(data, function (item) { // without the .d

However this is not working as it only selects one value and it is the ID only that is being selected as in this screenshot:

**Before selection:**

[image]

**After selection:**

[image]

I am not sure why this is happening, if you could help please..

**Update: this is the actual Json, after I fixed it. The only problem now is that it doesn't multi-select**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    debugger;
    $('#city').autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "Home/GetWhatever",
                data: "{ pre: request.term }",
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data, function (item) {
                        return {
                            SubCategoryName: item.SubCategoryName,
                            SubCategoryID: item.SubCategoryID,
                            json: item
                        };
                    }));
                },
                error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert(textStatus);
                }
            });
        },
        focus: function (event, ui) {
            $('#city').val(ui.item.SubCategoryName);
            return false;
        },
        select: function (event, ui) {
            $('#city').val(ui.item.SubCategoryName);
            return false;
        },
    }).data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
        return $("<li>")
        .append("<a>" + item.SubCategoryName + " " + item.SubCategoryID + "</a>")
        .appendTo(ul);
    };
});
```

** @Daedalus Data view from Fiddler**

I just noticed it is duplicated and this likely to be the reason it is not multi-selecting?
[image]

Comment: @Tomanow Thanks but isn't it this enough to do it:  $(function () {}). Which is already there as you see. I have moved to the main view from the PartialView (where it was) thought, but the error is still happening.

Comment: Ah did not see. On a side note, this looks strange to me: `data: "{ 'pre':'" + request.term + "'}"`. Shouldn't it be `data: { pre: request.term }`? You are sending a string...

Comment: sorry if this is way off base, but I don't see your data attribute setting anywhere: data("ui-autocomplete")

Comment: @Tomanow I am actually a total newbie to JQueryUI and I obtained this code from an this link here: http://dotnetawesome.blogspot.in/2013/12/autocomplete-multi-value-textbox-without-webservice.html

Comment: @jamesemanon isn't this set already. I have looked at Fiddler and it seems that it is bringing databack - however it doesn't show on the textbox. instead it shows the error message above.

Comment: @Tomanow I've changed it to data: { pre: request.term } but it is still showing the same error message. However the Json data is being returned as I can see from Fiddler.

Comment: Hey @t_plusplus I'm confused as to what the `.data('ui-autocomplete')` is doing. I can help you in chat if you like... [CHAT](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23598/jquery)

Comment: @Tomanow I tried to find you in the chat but it kept sending a parser error. I think the data("ui-autocomplete") display the autocomplete data. it is the dropdown shown in figure 1 if you. I have tried this code that you given me but the error returned after I escaped it - please see my edit. Thank you.

Comment: @t_plusplus Please show us the actual json you're sending to the function.

Comment: @Daedalus please have a look at the last edit, which I did to show the Json again (with fixes). It doesn't multi-select.

Comment: @t_plusplus I did, and while that is a javascript object, it isn't the json.  I need the actual data you are getting from the ajax request.  The raw stuff.  To be a little more specific... the above isn't json.  JSON, or javascript object notation, is a method of denoting data.  In the above, all you do is use the jQuery object to do some stuff.  However when json is referenced, it is the data that is being sent to those functions that is being referenced.

Comment: @t_plusplus So.. your data is an array of objects?  When I asked for the raw data, I didn't mean a representation of it, but the actual code that data echos out, should you do so in the browser console(console.log(JSON.stringify(data));). [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/wuzFK/)

Comment: @Daedalus I'm sorry I don't quiet get what you mean. I went to my browser's console and typed this console.log(data); but got an error. Could you please clarify more what to do to get it? The only problem now to solve it that the above only single-selects rather than multi-select.

Comment: @t_plusplus In your ajax request, you have `success: function(data) { /* stuff is done here */ }.`  Add `console.log(JSON.stringify(data));` to the top of that function, and post the result here.

Comment: @t_plusplus Also, this doesn't appear to be for any 'normal' internet browser.  Please specify what this is used in the context of.

Comment: @Daedalus ah ok I got you now, thanks for clarifying. This is it: [{"SubCategoryName":"Apollo Tt Bike 26\"","SubCategoryID":1},{"SubCategoryName":"Apollo Tt Bike 25\"","SubCategoryID":2},{"SubCategoryName":"Apollo Tt Bike 15\"","SubCategoryID":3},{"SubCategoryName":"Carrera Bike 26\"","SubCategoryID":4}]

Comment: @t_plusplus Working on this, but I need to be back in a bit.

Comment: @Daedalus ok then. thanks a lot of your help and time. I am also researching around this. much appreciated really.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Full disclaimer, most of the code in this answer was copied(then altered) from the [jQuery UI API manual page for Autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#multiple).

That out of the way, your autocomplete is not allowing for multiple selections for a simple reason: it requires a custom handler to be set up in order for such to happen, and you never set up that handler.

Secondly, the code is doing what its supposed to.. You specifically select the `SubCategoryID` property from your `item` object, which given your comment, contains the ID of the item.

Given what you have said in the question and comments, I would surmise this is not your goal.  So, that in mind, here is the correct code to do what I think you want to achieve.  I'm putting in comments to explain what I do(and again to note, the core of this is taken from the API page, with a slight alteration):

```
$(function () {
    $('#city').autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "Home/GetWhatever",
                data: "{ pre: request.term }",
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data, function (item) {
                        return {
                            SubCategoryName: item.SubCategoryName,
                            SubCategoryID: item.SubCategoryID,
                            json: item
                        };
                    }));
                },
                error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert(textStatus);
                }
            });
        },
        focus: function (event, ui) {
            /**
             * Here is the modifications I altered from the API manual page;
             * all I really added was extra focus event handling code and
             * an id field, if you just want the ids to be added to a
             * hidden input or such.
             */
            //Grab the current value of the input(s) and turn them into arrays
            var terms = this.value.split(/,\s*/),
                ids = $("#cityids").val().split(/,\s*/);
            //Remove the current input         ^ This is regex, it matches by            
            terms.pop();                      //  a comma followed by zero or
            ids.pop();                        //  more spaces.
            //Add the selected item to the end of the array(s)
            terms.push(ui.item.SubCategoryName);
            ids.push(ui.item.SubCategoryID);
            //Set the value of the inputs to the new strings.
            $("#city").val(terms.join(", "));
            $("#cityids").val(ids.join(", "));
            return false;
        },
        select: function (event, ui) {
            //Grab the current values of the input(s) and turn them into arrays
            var terms = this.value.split(/,\s*/),
                ids = $("#cityids").val().split(/,\s*/); 
            //Remove the current input                  
            terms.pop();
            ids.pop();
            //Add the selected item to the end of the array(s)
            terms.push(ui.item.SubCategoryName);
            ids.push(ui.item.SubCategoryID);
            //Add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
            terms.push("");
            ids.push("");
            //Set the value of the inputs to the new strings.
            $("#city").val(terms.join(", "));
            $("#cityids").val(ids.join(", "));
            return false;
        },
    }).data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
        return $("<li>")
            .append("<a>" + item.SubCategoryName + " " + item.SubCategoryID + "</a>")
            .appendTo(ul);
    };
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/YmpVM/)

**Update:**

In regards to my oversight regarding the search terms, the following should do it, as well as the delete term bit;

Replace your 'success' handler code/content with the following:

```
var terms = request.term.split(/,\s*/),
    cur_term;
// Get the current term
if (terms[terms.length - 1] == "") {
    cur_term = terms[terms.length - 2];
} else if (terms.length > 1) {
    cur_term = terms[terms.length - 1]
} else {
    cur_term = request.term;
}
response($.map(data, function (item) {
    var reqterm = $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(cur_term),
        //escape any regex
        reg = new RegExp("^"+reqterm,"gi"),
        //create the regex object with current term
        match = item.SubCategoryName.match(reg);
        //match the item name against the regex
    if (match !== null) {
        return { // match found, add object
            SubCategoryName: item.SubCategoryName,
            SubCategoryID: item.SubCategoryID,
            json: item
        }
    } else {
        return null; // No search term found, remove item from array.
    }
}));
```

The above searches for the current term in the data, only returning matches if any are found.

Secondly, insert this code before your `.data()` code, so it goes between the `})` and `.data()`; example: `}).data(/*etc*/)` becomes `}).keydown(/*etc*/).data(/*etc*/)`

```
.keydown(function(e) {
    var key = e.which;
    if (key == 8) { // backspace, add keycodes here to account for all keyboards
        var terms = $("#city").val().split(/,\s*/), //current terms
            ids = $("#cityids").val().split(/,\s*/), //current ids
            placeholder = terms[terms.length - 1]; //current placeholder
        // remove the current input, as well as the placeholder if applicable
        terms.pop();
        ids.pop();
        if (placeholder == "") {
            terms.pop();
            ids.pop();
        }
        // add the placeholders back
        terms.push(" ");
        ids.push(" ");
        $("#city").val(terms.join(", "));
        $("#cityids").val(ids.join(", "));
    }
})
```

[**DEMO_2**](http://jsfiddle.net/YmpVM/2/)

Comment: Thanks ever so much. I'll have a look how this will behave on my project when I get home tonight. But it all makes sense now and am sure it'll be just fine. Thanks again - too kind & informative.

Comment: thank you, this of course worked, the only issue with it is that it displays all data items; it doesn't filter them as per the user's character input. Also I wonder how could I possibly 'style' it in a way that if the user deletes the selection, it would be deleted all in one go rather than character by character as you press on back-space?

Comment: I am not sure whether this qualifies a new thread or not here.. @Daedalus

Comment: @t_plusplus I'll see what I can do.